# How post json body in ocelot.json route asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, ocelot

```
{
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/ProceedToBuy/PostWishList",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 8003
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/AddToWishlist",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "POST" ]
    }
```

I want to send json body with this route request.

Comment: Do you mean post your json  when request? You can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: thanks @JerryCai I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't have to route json the request will automatically route to the downstream path, we can just directly make request to upstream path with json and it'll work!